# AWS S3 upload with Swift error "encodeWithCoder"

Tags: ios, swift, upload, amazon-s3

Here's my code to do an upload of an image to a bucket AWS S3. (The credentials part in the appdelegate is goods).

```
    url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("tmp.jpg"))

    UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.photo.image, 1).writeToURL(self.url, atomically: true)

    uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()
    uploadRequest.bucket = "BUCKETNAME"
    uploadRequest.key = "filename.jpg"
    uploadRequest.body = url
    uploadRequest.uploadProgress = { (bytesSent:Int64, totalBytesSent:Int64,  totalBytesExpectedToSend:Int64) -> Void in
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() -> Void in
            println(totalBytesSent)
        })
    }

    AWSS3TransferManager.defaultS3TransferManager().upload(uploadRequest).continueWithBlock { (task) -> AnyObject! in
        if (task.error != nil) {
            if( task.error.code != AWSS3TransferManagerErrorType.Paused.hashValue
                &&
                task.error.code != AWSS3TransferManagerErrorType.Cancelled.hashValue
                )
            {
                //failed
                println("failed")
            }
        } else {
            //completed
            println("completed")
        }
        return nil
    }
```

The problem, i've got a crash with this message :

```
    -[AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fba9b63ddb0
    *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fba9b63ddb0'
```

Any ideas ? It's very difficult to find help with aws and swift.

Thanks !

Comment: hey have found the same issue very similar code, did you find how to fix it?

Comment: Yes, i've found my problem. It's was when i added the framework, i forgot to add the JSONS.